# Unable to check Cardboard XR Plugin in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr

I tried to create a project for cardboard VR. I imported the git VR package from this path [Click here to download VR GITHUB Path,](https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard-xr-plugin) Then in Project settings -> XR Plug-in Management I tried to check Cardboard XB Plugin, The package is not installed, I got the error message which is shown in the below screenshot.
[image]

Please tell me how to fix this issue

Error Message:

> XR Plug-in Managfement error. Failure reason: Error Message: Unable to add package [com.google.xr.cardboard]:
> Package [com.google.xr.cardboard] cannot be found.
> Error installing package com.google.xr.cardboard..
> check if there are any other in the console and make sure they are connected before trying again.
> UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunction()

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Make sure that `GIT` is installed on your PC, open the Package Manager and try to add the package via Git URL and use `https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard-xr-plugin.git` (see [Quickstart for Google Cardboard for Unity](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart))

Comment: I did install github on my PC & Download the package from the package manager. It downloaded perfectly. The problem will occur only when I tried to enable Cardboard XR Plugin in XR Plugin Management.

Comment: @derHugo The error message is clearly captured in the screenshot I posted. Again I update it in text form. You can find it on my post.